# Office.js onReady/initialize not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, word-addins

When running an addon in Internet Explorer (Or older versions of Office 365 which use Internet explorer to run addons, and not Edge like the newer version of Office 35) I get this error thrown:

```
SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.
```

However, it works fine in the newest version of Office (which uses Edge to run the addon internally) as well as in Office online using Chrome as a browser.

For reference, here is the relevant part of our index.js:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { initializeIcons } from "@uifabric/icons";
import App from "./App";

Office.initialize = () => {};

Office.onReady(() => {
  console.log("Office ready!");
  initializeIcons();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that some of the node modules we use do not work with IE11. Disabling these node modules fixed it. In the end, it did not have anything to do with office-js itself.

For anyone interested, the node modules that were breaking the app in IE11 were:

- querystring
- mobx (version 5)

Comment: How can we identify the packages causing this issue ? My ADD-IN also errors-out sometime on IE11 with the same error.